# chessboard type grid on windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Im trying to make a grid similar to the way a chessboard looks like in windows phone 8 but im new to developing for the windows phone and using xaml and am not sure where to begin i would like to update a change the colors of the "squares", most examples ive seen are in wpf and they use UniformGrid which is unavailable in windows phone.

so what ive found so far is

```
<Grid Margin="29,29.5,23,32.5" Height="500">
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource color}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        .
        . 
        .
</grid>
```

but is their a way to generate a grid of varing size such as 12x12 or 9x8 if i used the code above then i need to make a rectangle for every square which isnt what im going for.

So im just wondering what the xaml would look like it also seems that i need to use data bindings to update the UI. Is their any way to generate a visual grid and be able to update the contents inside. If anyone would could point me in the right direction that would really helpful.

Comment: You can find a custom implementation of UniformGrid for WP/Silverlight [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/uniform-grid/) and [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2012/02/07/a-uniformgrid-for-silverlight-windows-phone.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create a two-level view model of rows and cells. Bind the rows to an ItemsControl, then in the item template, bind the cells to another ItemsControl. Each cell will have a property to tell if it is even or odd, so you can achieve the checkerboard pattern. You can expose game state through additional properties of the cell to display board position through data binding.

Finally, since the cells will have a fixed size, wrap the whole thing in a Viewbox to fit it to your container.

The view models:

```
public class BoardViewModel
{
    private readonly int _rows;
    private readonly int _columns;

    public BoardViewModel(int rows, int columns)
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _columns = columns;
    }

    public IEnumerable<RowViewModel> Rows
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable
                .Range(0, _rows)
                .Select(row => new RowViewModel(row, _columns))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class RowViewModel
{
    private readonly int _row;
    private readonly int _columns;

    public RowViewModel(int row, int columns)
    {
        _row = row;
        _columns = columns;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CellViewModel> Cells
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable
                .Range(0, _columns)
                .Select(column => new CellViewModel(_row, column))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class CellViewModel
{
    private readonly int _row;
    private readonly int _column;

    public CellViewModel(int row, int column)
    {
        _row = row;
        _column = column;
    }

    public bool IsEven
    {
        get { return (_row + _column) % 2 == 0; }
    }
}
```

The value converter:

```
public class CellColorValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Application.Current.Resources[
            (bool)value == true
                ? "EvenCellColor"
                : "OddCellColor"];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CellColorValueConverter
        x:Key="CellColor" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <ItemsControl
            ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Rectangle
                                    Width="50"
                                    Height="50"
                                    Fill="{Binding IsEven, Converter={StaticResource CellColor}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. im new to windows phone development so the <window.Resources> seems to be unavailable in it, or im missing something.